# Magento unable to send emails to corporate domain

Tags: php, email, magento

I am facing a very weird issue in my Magento (v 1.9.2) store. 
I am able to send Low Inventory Notification email to gmail accounts but not to any corporate email accounts. I have tested for multiple corporate email accounts in different domains.
I am able to send New Order, Shipping confirmation etc. emails to the same corporate email accounts though.

I am unable to figure out what might be there issue, any hints will be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Please ask your server guys to add your corporate domain into the MX entry.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Suman but if you read my problem carefully. 
I am getting some reports by email on my corporate email account, but not getting only the Low Inventory Report. So my email account is fine.
Also, I am getting Low Inventory Report on my gmail email account, so Low Inventory Report email process seems to be working fine as well. 
Just the combination does not seem to be working.